# What is the role of the HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun\REGISTRY

Tags: windows-registry, microsoft-word-2013

I wrote a plugin for Word 2013, when I open an key and writes an value,  the value is not written in a specific key, but instead he appears under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun\REGISTRY`

I tried to write to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{DB38EDF5-34AE-4856-B536-DF3133DC860C}`.

The problem does not exist in Word 2010.

What is the role of this key? Why I can not write directly to key I want?

Comment: what is the key you are trying to write to?

Comment: Although this MS blog references Outlook it's the same deal with Word 2013 (if it is the click-and-run version which yours clearly is).  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stephen_griffin/2014/04/21/outlook-2013-click-to-run-and-com-interfaces/

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982431

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the new MS Office Click To Run technology.
See what [MS has to say](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2016/12/09/consdierations-while-readingwriting-registry-keys-under-hklm-from-office-addin-in-office-click-to-run/#comment-5815):

> Assume that in a Click-to-Run edition of a Microsoft Office application you run an Office add-in that creates custom registry entries under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM) hive. In this situation, the custom registry entries are created in a specific part of the Click-to-Run registry subkey. For example, if an add-in creates a registry entry under the HKLM/Software hive, the following registry entry is created:
>
> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Custrom-Registry-Entry
>
> This behavior is by design because Office Click-to-Run editions use Application Virtualization. Any custom registry entry under the Click-to-Run hive may be changed by any Office update because the Office Click-to-Run editions own the Click-to-Run registry entries. For example, any custom registry entry may be deleted after you install an Office update.